# How can one give webpage feedback on a long running task in Actix web?

Tags: rust, user-experience, actix-web, long-running-task

I might have missed it, but I cannot find how to give feedback to the user on the webpage during  a long running task in actix_web. Program is in Rust.

Abstracted I have a route on "/calculate" that does long calculation. I now have an async function async fn calculate(webdata,identity,..)-> impl Responder {........HttpResponse::Ok().body("Done result = xxxyxyxyy"} that is put as the handler in the route in the App.

This works well for short calculations. For long calculations all I can see that I have the option of blocking the webpage until I have the result or giving an immediate response and loosing the result into the great galactic void (or as in some examples I did find: into the println! terminal ;-)).

Actually, for long calculations, I would like to execute the following pattern when the user navigates to "/calculate".

1. show " Working....." as the HttpResponse
2. do the calculation
3. show "Done. Result = xxxyxyxyxyx" as the HttpResponse

I know of web:block and web:spawn,but these are useful to protect the calculations, but I can still  only manage to give one response from the handler. I  know how to do it in larger front-end frameworks, such as react, or maybe even yew but I am just curious if I am missing an obvious way to do this in actix_web only.

Note1: in my application it is not actually a calculation, but a more involved set of operations. Also the actual responses are a bit more fancy and colorful.

Note2: It would be ideal if the set-up is such that I can also have a "Stop"  button to stop the calculation. But that is the next step.

Comment: From my understanding, actix_web is a server framework, not a frontend frameworks. The way that all "frontend frameworks" (such as react) do this essentially boils down to the `calculate` route responding with an HTML page, which contains javascript which immediately calls another endpoint called e.g. `calc_rest` and when that 2nd request completes, updates the HTML contents. Since actix_web is not a frontend framework, it has no opinions about how you would use actix_web to do this process. You need "yet another" framework or roll your own.

Comment: Long running tasks is always a challenge in web programming, the request/response cycle is normally not very convenient, as it could timeout. The following solution may be of interest: Use a queue with background jobs. You would enqueue the task and get a job id, then you could a) poll periodically if the job is done (e.g. vía periodic ajax requests) and get the result to be displayed or b) use websockets and message the client (browser page) when the result is available.

Comment: Thank you. Will take react  or yew as front-end framework. Easy to do in both, but was hoping I would have missed some obvious server framework pattern.

Comment: Have you considered using SSE?

Comment: I have now decided to solve the problem by working with front-end vuejs in it's simplest form (an inline html component that handles the waiting and shows nice waiting graphics, results when they come in and a cancel button). The actix server side still does all the hard work in a pure request/response pattern. Works as a charm. 

Thanks community for helping me not to get stuck in trying to get the actix server framework to do something that won't work.